# Create a maven artifact with resource files in a custom folder

Tags: java, maven

I have a legacy project with a custom folder structure that holds some java classes and resource files. They are deployed as a single jar now there is a demand to deploy resource files to repository as a separate jar for use by a third party app.

The resources files are in folder */project/files/src/data-models*

What combination of maven plugins would be best for taking resource files from a custom folder, packaging it into a jar and deploying it?

Answer (score 2):

[Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

[Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/):

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Then you have to create an [assembly descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html) (`src.xml` in the above example) which specifies how to assemble your deliverable.